# Set Origin header to websocket-client

Tags: python, websocket, client

I'm using module called "websocket" for python, and I need to connect to server with different Origin header. I tried to use: `header = {"Origin: *"}` in WebSocketApp, but It makes 2 Origin headers.

```
--- request header ---
GET /?name=...&room=...&color=...HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: ...
Origin: ...
Sec-WebSocket-Key: rIfcXahGvdgTJ7WDhe023w==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: *
```

As you see, it has 2 origin headers, and I don't know how to fix it.
Full code:

```
from color import cprint
import websocket
import json as JSON

ws = websocket.WebSocket()

nick = input("Select name: ")
room = input("Select room: ")
color = input("Select color: ")

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    if JSON.loads(message)[0] == 1:
        print(JSON.loads(message)[1], ": ", JSON.loads(message)[2])

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    cprint("red", "### Disconnected from chat. ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('ws://...?name=%s&room=%s&color=%s' % (nick, room, color),
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close,
                              header = {"Origin: *"})
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to write origin to `ws.run_forever(origin=originVar)`.